# powershell escaping simple quote in counter name

Tags: powershell, performancecounter

I'm trying to get the counter (using a "PathsWithInstance") of one of my .NET programs.
It seems that I can not use the simple syntax because of simple quotes presence (french OS version):

```
Get-Counter -Counter "\Mémoire CLR .NET(MyProgram)\Nombre d'octets dans tous les tas"
```

I tried various escape strategies, but I always get an error telling that the specified couonter could not be found.

How should I escape that?

I've found this temporary workaround:

```
(Get-Counter -Counter "\mémoire clr .net(MyProgram)\*").CounterSamples | Where-Object {$_.Path -match "Nombre d'octets dans tous les tas"}
```

EDIT, due to comments:
So I still don't understand why this doesn't work:

```
Get-Counter -Counter "\mémoire clr .net(MyProgram)\nombre d'octets dans tous les tas"
```

And raises the following error (sorry in french):

```
Get-Counter : Le compteur spécifié n’a pas été trouvé.
Au caractère Ligne:1 : 1
+ Get-Counter -Counter "\mémoire clr .net(MyProgram)\nombre d'octets ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidResult : (:) [Get-Counter], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CounterApiError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetCounterCommand
```

Whereas this does work:

```
(Get-Counter -Counter "\mémoire clr .net(MyProgram)\*").CounterSamples | Where-Object {$_.Path -match "nombre d'octets dans tous les tas"}
```

Comment: `'this includes apostrophe''s'` -> `this includes apostrophe's` ?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_escape_characters?view=powershell-5.1

Comment: Thank you, @ConnorLSW I knew the trick of the  double simple quote, but in this case it doesn't work

Comment: Thank you @Manu, but I saw the doc and tried the back quote, the double single quote, the simple quote in the double quoted, but still doesn't work

Comment: @Christophe has Apostrophe issue. Kidding ;)

Comment: I know very well the problem Christophe as I'm french too. I just tried to use the same command with a `'` in it and it works.

Answer (score 0):

For me the trick was to replace french counters by english ones.

I did not manage to rename it with regedit, but I instead replaced files like described here : https://www.zabbix.com/forum/zabbix-cookbook/7524-how-to-force-perfmon-counters-description-to-be-in-english?p=182838#post182838

Script to rename files :

```
cd \windows\system32

move perfc00C.dat perfc00C_bak.dat
move perfd00C.dat perfd00C_bak.dat
move perfh00C.dat perfh00C_bak.dat
move perfi00C.dat perfi00C_bak.dat

copy perfc009.dat perfc00C.dat
copy perfd009.dat perfd00C.dat
copy perfh009.dat perfh00C.dat
copy perfi009.dat perfi00C.dat
```